# Match 2 users function in PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

So i have this project for school, i build a website where an User can match with an other User, and if they have both matched, something will happen.
Technically, what i want to do is add the User in my propriety "idCoach" and if the User that i have added, already have me in his propriety "idCoach" then apply a simple echo() for now.
Here is what i've tried to do this for now.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/user/match/{id}", name="match")
 */
public function match(ObjectManager $om, User $user)
{
    $currentUser = $this->getUser();
    $currentId = $currentUser->getId();
    $idCoach = $user->getIdCoach();

    if(in_array($currentId, $idCoach) {
       echo('bloup');
    } else {
       $currentUser->addIdCoach($user);
      }

    $om->persist($currentUser);
    $om->flush();
    dd($currentUser);

    return $this->render('profile/index.html.twig', [
        'oneuser' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

It doesn't work because it tells me that the in_array function expect that the second argument is an array and apparently i provide an object not an array so i'm out of solution.
Here is my User entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];

/**
 * @var string The hashed password
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
 */
private $picturePath;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $age;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2000, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SharingPage", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $sharingPage;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="idCoach")
 */
private $idSportif;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="idSportif")
 */
public $idCoach;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->idCoach = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return (string) $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}

public function getFirstName(): ?string
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

public function getLastName(): ?string
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

public function getPicturePath(): ?string
{
    return $this->picturePath;
}

public function setPicturePath(?string $picturePath): self
{
    $this->picturePath = $picturePath;

    return $this;
}

public function getGender(): ?string
{
    return $this->gender;
}

public function setGender(string $gender): self
{
    $this->gender = $gender;

    return $this;
}

public function getAge(): ?int
{
    return $this->age;
}

public function setAge(?int $age): self
{
    $this->age = $age;

    return $this;
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription(?string $description): self
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

public function getSharingPage(): ?SharingPage
{
    return $this->sharingPage;
}

public function setSharingPage(?SharingPage $sharingPage): self
{
    $this->sharingPage = $sharingPage;

    return $this;
}

public function getIdSportif(): ?self
{
    return $this->idSportif;
}

public function setIdSportif(?self $idSportif): self
{
    $this->idSportif = $idSportif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|self[]
 */
public function getIdCoach(): Collection
{
    return $this->idCoach;
}

public function addIdCoach(self $idCoach): self
{
    if (!$this->idCoach->contains($idCoach)) {
        $this->idCoach[] = $idCoach;
        $idCoach->setIdSportif($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeIdCoach(self $idCoach): self
{
    if ($this->idCoach->contains($idCoach)) {
        $this->idCoach->removeElement($idCoach);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($idCoach->getIdSportif() === $this) {
            $idCoach->setIdSportif(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method `getIdCoach` returns a `Collection` ( and more precisely an `ArrayCollection`).

In this interface, you have the method [`toArray()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.html#method_toArray) that you should use to have an array to pass at `in_array` method.